# Restart computer in [Code] in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to redesign my finish page.

What I did is I disabled the original finish page

```
DisableFinishedPage=true
```

and then created a custom page to replace it

```pascal
CreateCustomPage(wpInfoAfter, 'test', 'test');
```

My question is, after an user clicks the *Next* in my custom page, I would like the installer to restart the computer.

But how do I call restart within the *Next* button's event handler?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

What about not creating a custom finish page, but customizing the existing finish page? You can access it using [`WizardForm.FinishedPage`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses).

You can then ask Inno Setup to restart the machine for you, using [`NeedRestart` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents):

```pascal
function NeedRestart(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
end;
```